# Found the following, but they're either not files, or not executable:

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

```
rosrun using_markers basic_shapes
Couldn't find executable named basic_shapes below /home/tunc/catkin_wws/src/using_markers

rosrun using_markers basic_shapes.cpp
Found the following, but they're either not files, or not executable
/home/tunc/catkin_wws/src/using_markers/src/basic_shapes.cpp
```

I have problem like this. Can somebody help me? Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229863/found-the-following,-but-they%27re-either-not-files,-or-not-executable:/) by [tuncguclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26366/tuncguclu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You haven't compiled your workspace, this is why it only finds the `.cpp` and not the executable.

You have to run a `catkin_make` and have your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` configured correctly.

Check out section 4.3 and the last lines of section 4.1 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuncguclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26366/tuncguclu/) on 2016-03-23**:
Ok but when i try to run catkin_make an error like this occurs

```
The specified base path "/home/tunc/catkin_wws/src/using_markers" contains a package but "catkin_make" 
must be invoked in the root of workspace.
```

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-23**:
You need to run `catkin_make` in `/home/tunc/catkin_wws/`, not in `/home/tunc/catkin_wws/src/`.

**Comment by [tuncguclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26366/tuncguclu/) on 2016-03-23**:
catkin_make worked. I know i am asking too much :D but when i try to run rosrun using_markes basic_shapes it says

```
Error: package 'using_markes' not found
```

How do i handle that?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-23**:
Did you `source /home/tunc/catkin_wws/devel/setup.bash` after `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [tuncguclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26366/tuncguclu/) on 2016-03-23**:
No but i did now and still says the same thing.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-23**:
You need to do this in every terminal you use a ROS command.
Can you past the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` as well as the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` of your package? Please edit your question and format the files respectively using the preformatted text button (the one with 1s and 0s).